# How to find 3 largest even numbers in an array with C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement

I need to find 3 largest numbers in an array and then add them together.

For example:
Input: 3 4 7 10 11 16 16 23 26
Output: The sum of the 3 largest even numbers are: 16, 16, 26. The sum is 58

In my code, I'm getting weird outputs like "16, 1245782582792, 1".

Note: I can only use ifs/else, for/while loops, and arrays for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging on your own? With a debugger and/or debug print statement to trace the execution of your program?

Comment: You are scanning 9 numbers and then you do a check for 13 numbers. You are out of bounds

Comment: If your input is `... 16 16 23 26`, wouldn't the three largest numbers be 16, 23 and 26 (= 65)?

Comment: The numbers have to be even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You should only examine the array entries that are defined.  Instead, you are looking at the entire array, including the undefined portion from `nNumbers` through `MAX_NUMBERS-1`.  You will likely pick up garbage values there.  Change your `for` loops to:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++)
   ```
2. You are initializing `greatest1`, etc. to the first number in the array.  That doesn't work if the number is odd and happens to be large enough to block the even number you're looking for.
3. If one of the largest even numbers occurs more than once, you will ignore the duplicates.  For instance, if the largest number is 1000, and it occurs three times, you probably want to add all three and return 3000.  You can fix this by keeping track of the indices you have chosen, and only rejecting a duplicate if the index matches, rather than the value.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me out a lot :) My code is not outputting random numbers anymore. I'm not sure how to go about tracking indices as I have never done that before (just started C programming 2 weeks ago). Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Well, suppose `array[7]` is 120.  Instead of keeping 120 in `greatest1`, keep 7 in `greatest1_ix`.  When comparing values, use `array[greatest1_ix]` instead of `greatest1`.  So far the behavior will be unchanged.  But then, when checking for duplicates, use `greatest1_ix`.  That way it will only be seen as duplicate if it occurs at the same index in `array`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help :)